# Call to a member function error in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

The below method is returning an error after I added `&& in_array($itemID, $userItemIDS)` to the if statement.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

```
    /**
    * Deactivate item.
    *
    * @param (int) $itemID - Variable representing an item's id.
    */
    public function deactivate($itemID) {

        //get user item ids
        $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();

        if( $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET active = 0 WHERE id = ?") && in_array($itemID, $userItemIDS) )
        {
            $q->bind_param("i", $itemID);
            $q->execute();
            $q->close();
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: in_array function return only true and false not return a id you should pass the id not true and false. i think so for that the error is comming.

Comment: Just so we are all clear: If you remove the `in_array()` call inside the `if` statement, your code runs fine?

Comment: Yup ... code runs fine if I remove `in_array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate out the call to `prepare` and first check to make sure that the call succeeded:

```
$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET active = 0 WHERE id = ?");

if ($q != FALSE && in_array($itemID, $userItemIDS)) {
    $q->bind_param("i", $itemID);
    $q->execute();
    $q->close();
    return true;
}
```

This will also make your code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Nice and clean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because `$q` will equal the boolean result of the `&&` operator between

- your DB object object (considered positive if success)
- the `in_array` function (boolean in all cases)

**you need to bracket the assignment:**

```
public function deactivate($itemID) {

    //get user item ids
    $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();

    if( ($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET active = 0 WHERE id = ?")) 
              && in_array($itemID, $userItemIDS) ) {
        $q->bind_param("i", $itemID);
        $q->execute();
        $q->close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "assignation" is not a word in English ^ ^